# Ubuntu 18.04 crashes on Lenovo T480

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, crash

Ubuntu 18.04 has worked otherwise perfectly on my Lenovo T480, but now, for multiple times, when I get back to work in the morning it has crashed. I have set it not to suspend when plugged in. I just lock the screen and leave. It has never crashed while I'm using it so this is a bit weird. Any ideas? Too low CPU load during the night? :)

It seems I'm running 4.15.0-23-generic